# How do I access "named properties" in a GTK struct?

Tags: gtk, glib

I'm trying to get a GTK-3.0-based app to build and I need to modify some code so that it uses the "master" *property* in a struct:

https://developer.gnome.org/gdl/stable/GdlDockLayout.html#gdl-dock-layout-new

I have little experience programming with GTK, so I don't know how to access these properties. And unfortunately "property" is such an overloaded term that Google yields nothing useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use something like

```
GObject *master;
g_object_get (my_gdl_dock_layout_widget, "master", &master, NULL);

// Use master

// Once you've finished with master, don't forget to unref it
g_object_unref (master);
```

see the [GObject reference documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get) for details on `g_object_get`

Answer (score 1):

You use the `GObject` (the base class of most objects in GTK+ and related libraries) API.

The (rather sparse) [documentation is here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html).

Essentially, I think you're after the [`g_object_set_property()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-property) function.